# There's a way to access the document folder in iphone/ipad (real device, no simulator)?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, document

there's a way to access a real device (iphone/ipad) document folder? I realized an app that store some data in that folder and i wanted to check if all is going in the right way.

Comment: Sure: jailbreak, SSH.

Comment: are you talking about any app or the one you are developing?

Comment: did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377280/is-ios-developer-able-to-view-file-system) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201944/storing-and-reading-files-from-documents-directory-ios-5)

Comment: Ok, i'll check what ssh is. I'm talking of an app i'm developing. I'll check the links. Thanks!

Comment: if you look for a tool to read the files on the device the **[i-FunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com)** could be very useful for you. there is no need to jail-break the device.

Comment: Installed! It's fantastic! Exactly what i was looking for. If you write the comment like an answer i accept it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Follow the steps in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62828698/6296219 for MacOS Catalina

Comment: @GurunathSripad This link helped to solve my issue. Now i can view application data files on device...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To anyone looking out for the exact answer:-

1.Go to plist file of your project.

2.Add one row.

3.Then set the Boolean value of the property "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to "YES". (the key name is `UIFileSharingEnabled`)

And you are good to go.

Also note that you have to plugin the device in order to access the copied files (Programmatically). If you happen to go and try to access it on computer .. you wont be able to find the files.

Comment: I get access to document folder with iFunBox, it is quite simple.

Comment: If you want to be able to access the files in the iOS Files app, make sure to also enable `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` (in addition to enabling `UIFileSharingEnabled`).

Comment: Just wanted to mention for anyone trying to implement iOS file access for a Nativescript app, enabling both properties as Nick suggested work perfectly.

Comment: Note that if you right click on the plist editor you'll see an option for "Show Raw Keys / Values", click that to see names like UIFileSharingEnabled instead of the longer / more verbose names

Comment: Also, with the two keys that @NickTiberi mentioned, I am able to see the (plain text) files my app wrote directly in the Files app on iOS, no need to connect to iTunes / download files / write a program to do it. But I can transfer it to my computer using iTunes as needed, see [this guide](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301)

Comment: The Xcode plist editor label for `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace` is `"Supports opening documents in place"`

Answer (score 144):

You can do this without iTunes and even if the file is somewhere else in the sandbox other than Documents.

Go to Window/Devices in Xcode.

[image]

Next, select your device, and find the app in the list.

[image]

Now, look at the little gear icon at the bottom of the devices window. Click that bad boy.
[image]

See "Download Container..." in the list. Guess what that does? You got it. It downloads the whole sandbox with all the folders in the app's sandbox. Right click and "Show Package Contents".

This should let you see the sandbox of apps that have not yet been released. So, good for testing on a real device.

If you're testing on a simulator life is way easier. Just download the free app OpenSim [here](https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim) . Update: These days I prefer SimSim, also free [here](https://github.com/dsmelov/simsim).

Comment: That's worked with me, easy way for get get access to real document in iDevice.

Comment: Really nice! Thanks.

Comment: this one is right option. It really copy the whole app sandbox. Thanks.

Comment: This works very nice. Might want to add 'right click the .xcappdata -> Show Package Contents' to complete your answer.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. Much more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you this makes it so easy if u have Xcode. This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: This no longer works, at least not in Xcode 13.4.1. The Windows menu now shows "Devices and Simulators" and there's no gear any more.

Comment: Ahh. Now you open "Devices and Simulators", select your device in the left column, and in the right pane under "Installed Apps", highlight your app, and hit the (...) button, and from there you can download the container.

Comment: please let me know where this folder gets downloaded in mac

Comment: @ram880 see how Download Container has a `...` after it? that means you will select where to download the container to in the dialogue that pops up. try it.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I can see three interpretations:

1. You can plug your iPhone into iTunes to see your documents folder for any app with iTunesFileSharing enabled, including any apps you have written or are writing.
2. If this is your own app, and you need help reading files from the documents folder, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709705/read-text-file-in-document-folder-iphone-sdk).
3. If this is someone else's app, and you want to access the app's documents folder without iTunes and the app does not have implementation for what you want, then I am afraid some sort of jailbreaking and hacking is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, six months of app developing and i keep feeling like a newbie! ^^' Yea, i have to access the document folder with my own developed app, but not programmatically. The app write some files into the document folder, and i want to see the content of the document folder with my own eyes, in order the check if the app is doing what is meant to do. Check filename, and so on.

Comment: Then file sharing seems the way to go. This is a good tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app.
You could also use the emulator since all folders are accessible through the file system.

Comment: Good to know, i didn't thought about the simulator. Could be useful to check the funcionatily of the app on the new iphone, which i don't own. For the file sharing issue, i've installed iFunBox, as suggested before. It's very cool. I'll check the itunes solution too. Thank you!

Comment: It would have helped more had you mentioned the exact name of the property to set and where to set.

Answer (score 5):

[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) can help in figuring out for an iOS app. :)

Edit:

You are right, give a try to [iMazing](https://imazing.com/)

Comment: Just found that it seems like it's not doing this kind of access any more. Was using iExplorer in the past but no luck with current version.

Comment: I just used iExplorer `v4.2.8` and it worked for me—complete access to app container on a TestFlight build installed on a physical device.

Answer (score 2):

You can access documents directory from code using:

```
+ (NSString *) applicationDocumentsDirectory {    
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

And you can then go to terminal for the same path and check all the files.

e.g on my system its like this:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<deviceID>
```

Comment: This only works when using the simulator, not a real device

Answer (score 2):

## Quick Solution

Just add this key in our plist and you're good to go

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

Visit [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uifilesharingenabled) link for detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a tool that import file from iOS app document folder to Mac, install Apple configurator 2 (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Connect your device to Mac and in Apple configurator follow below steps

Double click on the Device

Choose Actions > Export > Documents.

Select the file inside app to export, then click Choose. Save the items to the desired location in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have a physical device you can add the UIFileSharingEnabled
   key in info.plist and set its value to YES
2. then run your app
3. open iTunes select device and goto file sharing and select your app
4. you will be shown files created by your app