# Possible to extract game files from ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently deleted some of my key IOS game files in Xcode by accident. Before deleting the said files, I uploaded my IOS game to my iPad as a test and it worked. I still have the working app on my iPad but I don't have the necessary files to run the game on my mac. Is it possible to extract the Xcode game files, that I lost, from my working game app on my iPad, and then add them into my Xcode project so that my game is restored?

The files that I lost took me many hours to program and it would be very helpful if I could find a way to retrieve them. Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'game files' do you mean source code, or, resources?

Comment: I deleted many .sks files and .swift files. Does that answer your question?

Comment: that's why source control is very important

Comment: You could try out if the files where backedup by `Time Machine`. Also start using a CSMS (like Git which is supported by Xcode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it's possible to access files inside your applications documents folder, it's not possible to retrieve Swift source files or indeed .sks SceneKit files, as they are compiled into the .app bundle.

You can download the app container and see what's salvageable though.

For information on how to do that, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219511/theres-a-way-to-access-the-document-folder-in-iphone-ipad-real-device-no-simu) answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no way to retrieve the files? It's unfortunate because I have the IOS app on my iPad and it works.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdamJones no problem, let me know if you need further help.

Comment: It didn't work, I found none of the files I wanted :( Any other options?

Comment: @AdamJones sorry, not other options than I'm aware of. You use any backup software or Time Machine for example? Do you have a local git repo?