# Where is .txt file getting saved Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This code running correctly. But I don't know where my .txt file is saving

```
public string PersonalFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

//Write Information to a Local File
public void WriteLocalFile(string FileName, string Data)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(PersonalFolderPath, FileName);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, Data);
}
//Load Information from a Local File
public string LoadLocalFile(string FileName)
{
    string filePath = Path.Combine(PersonalFolderPath, FileName);
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        showtext.Text= File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        return showtext.Text;
    }
    return null;
}

private void SaveButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WriteLocalFile("Burak.txt", text.Text);
}

private void LoadButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadLocalFile("Burak.txt");
}
```

How can I find it? Or another way?
Thank you.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your filePath and see the value there.

Comment: i did it and saw it. But Can i access it from Phone or Emulator ?

Comment: Accessing the file external from the app will be different on each platform, I recommend you go research how local files work for the platform you're testing on. Android or UWP will be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

**Simulator:**

Once you get the `filePath`, you can go to `Finder` -> select `Go` -> choose `Go To Folder...` and then type in your `filePath`. Click `Go` and you can get the document in the folder.

**Phone:**

You can view the documents by download container from your phone. You can refer to [There's a way to access the document folder in iphone/ipad (real device, no simulator)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219511/theres-a-way-to-access-the-document-folder-in-iphone-ipad-real-device-no-simu).