# swift how open my saved pdf with other app

Tags: swift, xcode, pdf, webview

I save a pdf on local like this :

```
   func saveMandatPdf(pdfBase64 : String, idMandat : String) -> Bool{
    guard
        var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
        let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: pdfBase64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
        else {
            return false
    }
    let fileName = "\(idMandat).pdf"
    documentsURL.appendPathComponent(fileName)
    do {
     try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL, options: .atomic)
        return true
    } catch {
     print(error)
        return false
    }
  }.
```

i checked that i can see the pdf with webview, so everything work the file is saved i can see it on seimulator tmp folder

but on a real device when i check on the application "books" i can't find this pdf files

[image: here is the application where is search foe my pdf]

thank you for your help

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219511/theres-a-way-to-access-the-document-folder-in-iphone-ipad-real-device-no-simu

Comment: @DharmeshKheni yes it helps but how can i save my file on a public folder that all the applications can see it ? application like books ?

Comment: you can use `UIActivityViewController` for that where users can choose if they want to save it to files

Comment: save to files, it's exactly what i need i will try it

Comment: @tamtoum1987 you can't save anything to Files. You need to allow the user to do so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456481/how-to-write-a-file-to-a-folder-located-at-apples-files-app-in-swift/46457518?r=SearchResults&s=1|51.5553#46457518. If you would like to make your document directory appear on the folder "On My Phone" of the Files app exposing it to other apps I can show you how to accomplish it.